# How to reference a file relative to the current dir in a shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, java

I want to run a shell script that copies a file. I don't like to make absolute reference to that file.

```
myproject/target/myapp.jar
myproject/docs/copy.sh
```

copy.sh contains:
`scp ~/Projects/myproject/target/myapp.jar user@myip:/var/www`

Question: how can I run the `copy.sh` shell script and reference the `myapp.jar` relative? Like first walking up one folder, and then going into `/target`?

Comment: `../../target/myapp.jar` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `myproject/docs/copy.sh` you want 2 directories up and into target. You can do that with ...

```
../../target/myapp.jar
```

This though ...

```
scp ~/Projects/myproject/target/myapp.jar user@myip:/var/www
```

I would use a variable and set it at the beginning of your script or from a configuration. You can't use ../../ inside the `scp` when you have "Projects" above it.

This will give you the directory your script is in:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
```